# C++11, const data members, std::inserter, copy

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, inserter

There is a simple example of the class Test

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct MinMax { T min, max; };

template <typename T>
using TList = std::vector<T>;

template <typename T>
class Test
{
   private:
      const T a, b;         
      const MinMax <T> m;   
   public:
      Test() : a(0), m{ 0, 0 }, b(0.0) {};
   public:
      T getA() const { return a; }
      MinMax <T> & getMinMax() const { return m; }
      T getB() const { return b; }
      Test(const Test &t) : a(t.a), b(t.b), m(t.m ) {}
};
```

with the constant data members. Instead of the constructor, the data are not changed. I would like to copy the vector of Test objects to another vector using std::inserter. I am surprised that the copy constructor is not sufficient

```
int main()
{
   TList <Test <double> > t1;
   TList <Test <double> > t2;
   Test<double> t;
   t1.push_back(t);
   std::copy(t2.begin(), t2.end(), std::inserter(t1, t1.begin()));

   return 0;
}
```

and the following compiler error appears (VS2015):

```
Error   C2280   'Test<double> &Test<double>::operator =(const Test<double> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  Const
```

Is it possible to let the data members const and perform a copy in a different way (some hack :-))? Or an operator = must be defined, so the data members cannot be const (it is imppossible to assign to an object with const data members)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure, try `std::move()`?

Comment: With const data members, neither copy assignment nor move assignment can be enabled (without horrid const cast hacks)

Comment: @Richard Hodges: I was afraid that it was impossible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An insert to a `vector` reassigns all elements after the inserted element and assigns the inserted element to the freed up slot.

In other words, **you can't** because the Standard requires the elements of standard containers to be `Asssignable` (have `a = b` defined) to offer full functionality.

Apart from the obvious solution of writing your own `operator=` you can also add elements with const members to a `vector` by pushing back:

```
std::copy(t2.begin(), t2.end(), std::back_inserter(t1));
```

but that's kind of working against the Standard; `push_back` doesn't happen to need assignability but other functions may.

Or, you can use a container that doesn't require assignability to insert, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
using TList = std::list<T>;
```

trading off all the benefits of contiguous memory cache locality of a `vector`.

On a closing note, I tend to avoid declaring data members of my structures `const` because of such problems with generic containers that require assignability under the hood. Notice that in your example removing `const` from private members would leave you with good-enough read-only fields (that can be accessed only via getters from outside).